# PDO equivalent of pg-result-seek

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Anybody knows the PDO equivalent of [pg-result-seek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-seek.php)? I want to rewind a dataset using Postgre.

Comment: do not rewind. Store result in array instead.

Comment: Care to elaborate? My dataset is small but there is a large number of fields. Putting all that in an array seems much less practical than rewinding.

Comment: If you are relying on Postgres-specific functionality you might consider using a Postgres library instead of PDO.

Comment: If you're going to show your fields on HTML page, storing them in array is the only sane way, mind you

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of the `fetch` function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

But I don't see the need to do that, if you select the rows, you need it (all)...

Answer (score 1):

PDO's [query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) method will return a [PDOStatement Object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). There is no equivalent to seek to a specific record like you are asking. One alternative might be to use the [fetchAll()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method and then grab the Nth record you are looking for.

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

$result[N] would contain the row you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but I am not looking for the nth record. Rather, I want to run the loop twice.

Comment: You can easily rewind the array and iterate it again. In fact, that may be preferred in case the db libfary or class changes no change is needed here

Answer (score 1):

If Database Permits, Use  PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS or PDO::FETCH_ORI_REL,

Eg.

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS, 671);
```